How do I find number of screws in this image?

I tried binary image and then dilation but it didn't work, I tried using sift and flann but couldn't find good enough lowe's ratio to get 95% accuracy.
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('20240713_194541.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread('screw.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)  # or pass an empty dictionary

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

img_matches = cv2.drawMatches(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good_matches, None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

cv2.imwrite("match.jpg", img_matches)


Are you looking for a solution specifically with traditional image processing or are you okay with a ML/AI based solution? A tip would be to 'solve' the easy problem i.e. the screws that are separable and easily found. then remove from your problem and work on an algorithm that handles the 'suspect' overlapping items.

halcon has a 3d-model-to-image-shape-matching function. So with that you could try to find each single screw. That would fit welll to the process suggested by @JasonChia

If you’re willing to put a little bit more effort into placing the screws on that surface, this goes from a devilishly hard problem to a trivial one.

"mechanical sorting" often also sorts for orientation, paired with vibration to bounce the items until they happen to be right side up. you should consider that. that's how automated optical inspection is done in industry. -- feature matching will do nothing useful here. too many instances of the same thing.

Maybe weighing is another option.

Like suggested, improving the sorting/screw placement would make this problem really easier.
If this is not an option, and you require precise counting, a small ML model would be the way to go. Something like: detect screws groups with the code below and apply some small detection/regression model on top of  that to count screws.
Assuming you can tolerate some kind of unprecise counting, this code estimate the typical size of a screw, detect screw groups and estimate the number of screws in this group based on the group area.
In the case of your image it get the number of screws correct.
You can improve on this base to make it better (by making the overlap_coef based on the group appearance for example). But it will likely stay limited and hard to port if the task change, even slightly.
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 

def resize_aspect_ratio(img, height = None):
    original_height, original_width = img.shape[:2]
    aspect_ratio = original_width / original_height
    new_width = int(height * aspect_ratio)
    return cv2.resize(img, (new_width, height))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # Parameters set looking at the histogram below, this is brittle
    min_screw_area = 30
    max_screw_area = 200
    overlap_coef = 1.05 # Blobs of screw looses area because of overlaping, this correct that a little

    img = cv2.imread("<path_to_your_image>")
    img = resize_aspect_ratio(img, 800) # resize image for display + lets not use such a big image for now
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
    thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh) # inverse the image so that objects of interest are white

    # Find the contours and remove small ones (noise)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = list(filter(lambda cnt: cv2.contourArea(cnt) > min_screw_area, contours)) 

    # Compute contours area and assuming most of the screws are separated compute typical size of a screw
    areas = [cv2.contourArea(cnt) for cnt in contours] 
    median_area_screw = np.median(areas)

    # Number of screws = individual screws + multiple_screw_areas / typical size of a screw
    multiple_screw_areas = list(filter(lambda area: area > max_screw_area, areas))
    num_screws = sum([np.round(area*overlap_coef/median_area_screw ) for area in multiple_screw_areas]) 
    num_screws += len(areas) - len(multiple_screw_areas)

    print(f"Estimated number of screws: {num_screws}")

    # Display some info for experimentation
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > max_screw_area:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1) 
        else:
            cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], -1, (0, 80, 255), 1) 
    cv2.imshow('Contour', img) 
    plt.hist(areas, bins=100)
    plt.show()
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


thanks! I eventually figured out that by using series of distance transforms and thresholding, I could separate the screws enough to draw contours around them. but apart from it this is a very novel solution

@Ecstacy Great ! Don't hesitate to share your solution, so that it can benefit others.
